# Python: Full-duplex "wrapper" for half-duplex serial port?

Tags: python, serial-port, uart, full-duplex

I have a serial device (point-to-point radio) that I'm now somewhat convinced is half-duplex UART. The datasheet is not in English and the translation is bad, so between that and my observations I'm going to assume it is.

My application expects a full-duplex serial port to operate correctly, so I'm wondering how easy it would be to implement a "wrapper" around the physical ports that buffers data at half the rate and appears full-duplex to the application. The access to the actual port would be time-sliced and maybe use escaped control characters for a flow control of sorts.

To that end, I found [this](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualSerialPorts/) virtual serial port implementation, which maybe could be modified.

I'm not very good at software, so it would take me longer messing around with it than somebody who knows what they're doing - so, does something like this already exist?

Cheers,
R

Comment: This is likely to be pretty complex. If you're not an experienced programmer, you either have to find an existing solution or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: The device also has an RS485 interface - which is telling as that usually is half-duplex. I I wonder if they make RS232-RS485 converters that are full-duplex on the RS232 end...

Comment: Your userspace program should not have to care if the link is full or half duplex. Your end is fully buffered, and the device driver should handle any RX/TX control (unless there's explicit information indicating otherwise). Most message exchange protocols are simple request-response dialogs with a master-slave relationship, so a full-duplex link is typically underutilized.  "*... implement a "wrapper" around the physical ports that buffers data at half the rate*" - Huh? Half the rate?

Comment: I'm putting a ppp link over UART - which expects a full-duplex connection. It breaks with this radio, because it CANNOT send and receive at the same time. ppp explicitly calls out that it doesn't work with half-duplex links - so I'm trying to figure out how to make that work here. I have to take care of both ends.

Comment: "*I'm putting a ppp link over UART - which expects a full-duplex connection.*" - These sites contradict your statement: (1) http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_PPPOverviewHistoryandBenefits-2.htm and (2) https://linux-ppp.vger.kernel.narkive.com/Xcw4wgUF/ppp-over-rs-485 and (3) https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/connectedgrid/cgr1000/1_0/software/configuration/guide/scada/scada1/sca_ppp_cgr1000.pdf

Comment: I think they don't: The first link DOES says "'It is supported on both synchronous and asynchronous lines, and can operate in half-duplex or full-duplex mode." - but not how. I've already read the 2nd, and the 3rd makes no mention of how to actually tell ppp to use half-duplex. 

The 2nd says: "The nasty bit is the half-duplex nature. [OP] is going to have to figure out how to make this half-duplex medium appear to be full-duplex, with asynchronous transmission...." - which is exactly what I'm trying to do, so I believe my question still stands. I would love to be proven wrong or shown how!

Comment: Re-read the #2 link carefully. The negativity is for >2 RS-485 nodes. The OP reports he already has a 2-node setup functioning; he wants to increase his setup to more nodes. That's why he getting skeptical/negative responses. You stated that you have a "*point-to-point radio*". Isn't that just 2 nodes?

Comment: That's true. And yes, mine is point-point. FWIW - the RS485 connection isn't active in my hardware version, so I'm stuck with UART w/ 2 data lines. And to an extent, it "works" - in that ppp makes a connection and doesn't drop it. But a ton of data gets lost and I can't get anything through reliably.
I did write a rudimentary version of the solution I was getting at / asking about (probably very poorly); it does work much better in terms of successful data transmission. I'm def sending a ton of extra control characters so it's really slow 0 there have got to be better / existing solutions!